# Slowing Down Transition of Push Segue

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I was wondering if there is a way to slow down 'push segue & back' like Tinder & Snapchat does. It's like normal segue but it's somehow transiting slowly.

I normally handle push segues with setting up a Push notification on Storyboard and programatically calling the segue *(clicked on NavBarItem and push segued to new UIViewController)*:

```
func settingsTapped() {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("NewsToSettings", sender: nil)
}
```

---

It there a way to

- enable slowing down segue globally for the whole app?
- or should I do it maually for each segue? If so, what is the appropriate way?

Comment: If you create your own transition animation, you can have the time delay you want.
Its not simple to explain how to do it, i will just put a link.
https://www.raywenderlich.com/110536/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was wondering if there is a way to slow down 'push segue & back' like Tinder & Snapchat does. It's like normal segue but it's somehow transiting slowly.

As you've been told, you simply write a custom transition animation. Give the navigation controller a delegate and implement `navigationController:animationControllerForOperation:fromViewController:toViewController:`. Basically then you just supply an object that implements the UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning protocol. As part of that, you get to specify the animation duration.

> enable slowing down segue globally for the whole app?

If all your navigation controllers have this same delegate, or if all the delegates supply this same UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning object, all push / pop transitions will use the same code and will work the same way.